# Linux C: what happens to unused file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

(apologies for not taking care of my accepts lately - will do so as soon as I get some time; just wanted to ask this question now that it occurred)

Consider the following C program:

```
int main(void) {
  write(3, "aaaaaa\n", 7);
  write(2, "bbbbbb\n", 7);
  write(1, "cccccc\n", 7);
  return 0;
}
```

I build and run it from the `bash` shell like this:

```
$ gcc -o wtest wtest.c
$ ./wtest 3>/dev/stdout
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
```

The way I see it, in this case, due to the shell redirection of fd 3 to `stdout`, that file descriptor is now "used" (not sure about "opened", since there is no opening of files, in the C code at least) - and so we get the `cccccc` string output to terminal, as expected.

If I don't use the redirection, then the output is this:

```
$ ./wtest 
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

Now fd 3 is not redirected - and so `cccccc` string is not output, again as expected.

My question is - what happened to those `cccccc` bytes? Did they dissapear in the same sense, as if I redirected fd 3 to `/dev/null`? (as in:

```
$ ./wtest 3>/dev/null
```

)

In addition, assuming that in a particular case I'd like to "hide" the fd 3 output: would there be a performance difference between redirecting "`3>/dev/null`" vs. not addressing fd 3 in the shell at all (in terms of streaming data; that is, if fd 3 outputs a really long byte stream, would there be an instruction penalty per byte written in the "`3>/dev/null`" case, as opposed to not addressing fd 3)?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time, this is not a forum but a Q/A site.

Comment: I'm slightly confused here, because the quoted program doesn't match the quoted outputs? "cccccc" is not written to fd 3, but to fd 1?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is - what happened to those cccccc bytes?

nothing. you failed to capture the return code of `write`, it should tell you that there was an error and `errno` should tell you what the error was

You also seem to have a questionable concept of what is persistent, the "bytes" are still sitting in the string literal where the compiler put them from the beginning. `write` copies byte to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Jens is right. If you run your program under strace on both situations, you'll see that when you redirect, the write works - because the shell called pipe() on your behalf before fork'ing your executable.

When you look at the strace without the redirection:

```
write(3, "aaaaaa\n", 7)                 = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
write(2, "bbbbbb\n", 7bbbbbb)                 = 7
write(1, "cccccc\n", 7cccccc)                 = 7
```

Which reminds us of the best practice - always check your return values.

Comment: Redirection to a file is handled with `open`, not `pipe`.

Comment: In the case of the shell, wouldn't that be pipe, get two descriptors, then dup2(3,new_in_fd), open dest file, dup2(new_out_fd,dest fd) ?

Comment: No pipes are opened unless you have a `|` in the command. The shell just opens the file, forks, dups the fd in the child and execs the required program. You can verify this by passing fd's to a C program that tests if they're pipes with `fstat` and `S_ISFIFO`.

Comment: That would work two, but I believe it is not what appears in Stevens. Thanks.